# Excel VBA -> Last date/time save + automatically update

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel document and sheet name: Overview

Because a lot of people modify this workbook, I want to add in B1 cell user ID (computer name) + date/time (so person who last modify sheet and date & time when this was happened)

I open macro tool (alt+F11) -> I use this for first time:

**1. create new module and add code:**

```
Function LastSaveDate()
 Application.Volatile True
 LastSaveDate = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)  
End Function
```

**2. click on left side inside of Macro... "Thisworkbook" and add following code:**

> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
> MsgBox Date
> Worksheets("Overview").Range("B1").Value = Date
> End Sub
> ```

What I'm doing wrong, excel in B1 cell showing "12.11.2013 18:35:14"  (I use in this cell: =LastSaveDate()       ) also showing right date and time, but when I save (as enabled macro document) it and reopen there is just showing ""12.11.2013  0:00:00" and there is no code in this cell B1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Workbook_Open()` macro is overriding the formula you put into cell B1: `=LastSaveDate()` with the current date.

To prevent this you need to  either delete that Macro or comment out the line:

```
Worksheets("Overview").Range("B1").Value = Date
```